# Where is specification for hex_md5 method in MongoDB shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I searched through many and many pages on the Internet and could not find anywhere a definition or specification of `hex_md5(str)` method in MongoDB shell. Did I missed it or it just does not exists?

Does it comes from Javascript itself? Chrome console does not know about this method. OR perhaps it is coming from Node.js somehow? I spend quite some good hours searching for this.

Additional, I would like to know what other builtin hash functions are available in MongoDB?

Comment: It's built into the shell. The MongoDB shell is a JavaScript REPL, but of course it's actually written in another language and implements a JavaScript engine. When you use these engines in your own program ( the MongoDB shell actually uses Mozilla SpiderMonkey, though it *used to be* V8 ) you can actually allow native coded methods to be called as JavaScript functions. That is the case of how it is implemented in the `mongo` shell. Not certain of what use to you that information  would be. Plenty of sources around for your own `hex_md5` implementation if you want one.

Comment: @NeilLunn If you make your this comment as an answer, I'll mark that as accepted.